# Numpy - Calculate the sum of the function over corressponding elements in two arrays

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a function that accepts two 3 x 3 numpy arrays and returns a scalar. I have two numpy arrays containing 3 x 3 arrays. The two arrays are of the same size. I want to find the sum of the function applied to the corresponding elements (3 x 3 matrices) in the two arrays efficiently.

I tried using zip by `np.sum([your_function(matrix_1, matrix_2) for matrix_1, matrix_2 in zip(array_1, array_2)])` but it's too slow.

Comment: How is it too slow? What makes you think that there could be a more efficient method? And, most importantly, **what exactly are you doing**? We can't comment on optimization issues without a reproducible example of what you are doing (including the function).

Comment: Please share `your_function` and provide an example of input. Note that Numpy is not design for operating on many small arrays. In fact, CPython is also not efficient in this case. The function should be vectorized to be fast, but we cannot help you with more information on the target function. Also note that Numpy cannot operate efficiently on lists. It just transform lists to arrays which is certainly less efficient than doing a basic CPython sum here by calling `sum` instead of `np.sum`.

Comment: As long as `your_function` has to be called once for each matrix pair there isn't much you can do to speed it up.  That's the big time consumer, not the iteration or `sum`.  Python `sum` may be bit faster than `np.sum` when working with a list comprehension.